# Transitive Library Includes in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dependencies

Let's say I have a static library A, which uses static library B. Then let's say I have an executable C that uses things in both libraries A and B.

Should I have C explicitly link w/ libraries A and B, or just library A, since A links with B?

ps. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0):

C must link with both A and B, there is no way for a static library to "use" another static library. When the .lib file for A is built, it will contain only external references to B, it will not bring in the actual code in the B library.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. What if A is a static library that links in B? Wouldn't all the references for B then be inside of A?

Comment: The Link Library Dependencies option in Visual Studio allows one library to contain all the references and definitions from another library.

Comment: Note that "Link Library Dependencies" only affects the Linker (link.exe) and not the Librarian (lib.exe). Turning this option on is an alternative to manually specifying the .lib files in the "Additional Dependencies" option in Linker/Input.

Comment: If library B is set as a dependency of library A (either through Frameworks and References, or "Project/Project Dependencies..."), then any application or .DLL project which depends on library A (either through Frameworks and References, or "Project/Project Dependencies...") will have the built outputs of both library A and library B linked in.

You can try this yourself, build with the option both on and off and note that the resulting .lib files are identical.